# Error: Column named cannot be found in 'df'

Tags: r, move

Appreciate if anyone could take a look at this. Thank you!

Having trouble with the move package in R--trying to convert it to the  move class before the next step of animating it

```
df<- structure(list(location.long = c(103.788045, 103.788979, 103.788979, 
103.788979, 103.789537, 103.788979, 103.789075, 103.789075, 103.784314, 
103.784314, 103.784814, 103.784814, 103.785765, 103.78625, 103.78456, 
103.78411, 103.78411, 103.78482, 103.78482, 103.78484), location.lat = c(1.403669966, 
1.400432959, 1.400432959, 1.400432959, 1.400409993, 1.400432959, 
1.399945971, 1.399945971, 1.40191203, 1.40191203, 1.402777964, 
1.402777964, 1.403566031, 1.403750014, 1.4021, 1.40206, 1.40206, 
1.40229, 1.40229, 1.40231), timestamp = structure(1:20, .Label = c("12/3/20 10:09", 
"12/3/20 16:05", "12/3/20 16:35", "12/3/20 17:05", "12/3/20 17:35", 
"12/3/20 18:05", "12/3/20 18:35", "12/3/20 19:05", "12/3/20 7:09", 
"12/3/20 7:39", "12/3/20 8:12", "12/3/20 8:40", "12/3/20 9:09", 
"12/3/20 9:39", "12/6/19 16:40", "12/6/19 17:10", "12/6/19 17:40", 
"12/6/19 18:10", "12/6/19 18:40", "12/6/19 19:10", "14/11/19 10:05", 
"14/11/19 16:05", "14/11/19 16:35", "14/11/19 16:45", "14/11/19 16:56", 
"14/11/19 17:05", "14/11/19 17:35", "14/11/19 18:05", "14/11/19 18:35", 
"14/11/19 19:00", "14/11/19 19:05", "14/11/19 7:05", "14/11/19 7:35", 
"14/11/19 7:54", "14/11/19 8:05", "14/11/19 8:14", "14/11/19 8:24", 
"14/11/19 8:35", "14/11/19 9:05", "14/11/19 9:35", "14/2/20 16:10", 
"14/2/20 17:53", "14/2/20 18:10", "14/2/20 18:46", "14/2/20 19:15", 
"14/2/20 7:20", "14/2/20 7:55", "14/2/20 8:22", "14/2/20 8:52", 
"14/2/20 9:28", "14/2/20 9:56", "15/10/19 10:08", "15/10/19 16:25", 
"15/10/19 16:55", "15/10/19 16:59", "15/10/19 17:25", "15/10/19 17:55", 
"15/10/19 18:25", "15/10/19 18:55", "15/10/19 19:01", "15/10/19 7:00", 
"15/10/19 7:09", "15/10/19 7:30", "15/10/19 7:39", "15/10/19 8:00", 
"15/10/19 8:09", "15/10/19 8:30", "15/10/19 8:39", "15/10/19 9:09", 
"15/10/19 9:39", "15/5/19 10:10", "15/5/19 10:25", "15/5/19 10:40", 
"15/5/19 11:10", "15/5/19 11:40", "15/5/19 12:20", "15/5/19 12:30", 
"15/5/19 12:40", "15/5/19 13:00", "15/5/19 13:10", "15/5/19 13:15", 
"15/5/19 13:23", "15/5/19 13:40", "15/5/19 14:06", "15/5/19 14:10", 
"15/5/19 14:40", "15/5/19 15:05", "15/5/19 15:10", "15/5/19 15:30", 
"15/5/19 15:40", "15/5/19 16:00", "15/5/19 16:10", "15/5/19 16:30", 
"15/5/19 17:40", "15/5/19 17:50", "15/5/19 17:58", "15/5/19 18:05", 
"15/5/19 18:10", "15/5/19 18:40", "15/5/19 18:43", "15/5/19 19:00", 
"15/5/19 7:45", "15/5/19 8:13", "15/5/19 8:38", "15/5/19 9:10", 
"15/5/19 9:32", "15/5/19 9:44", "16/12/19 10:00", "16/12/19 16:20", 
"16/12/19 16:50", "16/12/19 17:20", "16/12/19 17:50", "16/12/19 18:20", 
"16/12/19 18:50", "16/12/19 7:00", "16/12/19 7:30", "16/12/19 8:00", 
"16/12/19 8:30", "16/12/19 9:00", "16/12/19 9:30", "16/12/19 9:43", 
"16/5/19 10:00", "16/5/19 10:23", "16/5/19 10:36", "16/5/19 12:30", 
"16/5/19 13:00", "16/5/19 13:30", "16/5/19 16:30", "16/5/19 17:00", 
"16/5/19 17:30", "16/5/19 19:00", "16/5/19 19:30", "16/5/19 7:00", 
"16/5/19 7:15", "16/5/19 7:18", "16/5/19 7:30", "16/5/19 8:00", 
"16/5/19 8:30", "16/5/19 8:48", "16/5/19 9:00", "16/5/19 9:13", 
"16/5/19 9:30", "17/5/19 10:10", "17/5/19 10:40", "17/5/19 10:54", 
"17/5/19 11:10", "17/5/19 11:32", "17/5/19 11:40", "17/5/19 12:10", 
"17/5/19 13:10", "17/5/19 14:10", "17/5/19 14:24", "17/5/19 14:40", 
"17/5/19 15:00", "17/5/19 15:10", "17/5/19 15:18", "17/5/19 15:40", 
"17/5/19 16:10", "17/5/19 16:40", "17/5/19 17:10", "17/5/19 17:40", 
"17/5/19 18:00", "17/5/19 7:10", "17/5/19 7:40", "17/5/19 7:56", 
"17/5/19 8:07", "17/5/19 8:40", "17/5/19 9:10", "17/5/19 9:40", 
"17/9/19 10:00", "17/9/19 16:05", "17/9/19 16:35", "17/9/19 16:45", 
"17/9/19 17:05", "17/9/19 17:35", "17/9/19 18:05", "17/9/19 18:35", 
"17/9/19 19:05", "17/9/19 7:00", "17/9/19 7:10", "17/9/19 7:25", 
"17/9/19 7:30", "17/9/19 7:40", "17/9/19 7:55", "17/9/19 8:00", 
"17/9/19 8:20", "17/9/19 8:22", "17/9/19 8:25", "17/9/19 8:30", 
"17/9/19 8:35", "17/9/19 8:47", "17/9/19 8:55", "17/9/19 9:00", 
"17/9/19 9:25", "17/9/19 9:30", "17/9/19 9:55", "18/6/19 16:10", 
"18/6/19 16:40", "18/6/19 17:10", "18/6/19 17:40", "18/6/19 18:10", 
"18/6/19 18:40", "18/6/19 19:10", "20/11/19 10:00", "20/11/19 7:00", 
"20/11/19 7:30", "20/11/19 8:00", "20/11/19 8:10", "20/11/19 8:30", 
"20/11/19 9:00", "20/11/19 9:30", "21/11/19 16:05", "21/11/19 16:17", 
"21/11/19 16:35", "21/11/19 17:05", "21/11/19 17:35", "21/11/19 18:05", 
"21/11/19 18:35", "21/11/19 19:05", "21/5/19 10:08", "21/5/19 7:08", 
"21/5/19 7:38", "21/5/19 8:08", "21/5/19 8:48", "21/5/19 9:11", 
"21/5/19 9:51", "22/7/19 18:05", "22/7/19 18:35", "22/7/19 18:57", 
"22/7/19 19:11", "22/7/19 7:18", "22/7/19 7:50", "22/7/19 7:52", 
"24/2/20 16:35", "24/2/20 16:36", "24/2/20 16:48", "24/2/20 16:54", 
"24/2/20 17:05", "24/2/20 17:10", "24/2/20 17:35", "24/2/20 18:05", 
"24/2/20 18:30", "24/2/20 18:35", "24/2/20 19:05", "24/2/20 7:25", 
"24/2/20 7:52", "24/2/20 8:16", "24/2/20 8:45", "24/2/20 9:15", 
"24/2/20 9:45", "24/3/20 10:00", "24/3/20 16:00", "24/3/20 16:30", 
"24/3/20 17:00", "24/3/20 17:30", "24/3/20 18:00", "24/3/20 18:30", 
"24/3/20 19:00", "24/3/20 7:00", "24/3/20 7:30", "24/3/20 8:00", 
"24/3/20 8:30", "24/3/20 9:00", "24/3/20 9:30", "24/5/19 16:30", 
"24/5/19 16:56", "24/5/19 17:02", "24/5/19 17:16", "24/5/19 17:30", 
"24/5/19 17:49", "24/5/19 18:00", "24/5/19 18:30", "24/5/19 18:38", 
"24/5/19 18:49", "24/5/19 19:00", "24/5/19 19:30", "25/5/19 10:00", 
"25/5/19 16:00", "25/5/19 16:30", "25/5/19 17:00", "25/5/19 17:30", 
"25/5/19 17:40", "25/5/19 18:00", "25/5/19 18:18", "25/5/19 18:24", 
"25/5/19 18:27", "25/5/19 19:00", "25/5/19 19:30", "25/5/19 7:48", 
"25/5/19 8:18", "25/5/19 8:48", "25/5/19 9:18", "25/5/19 9:48", 
"25/6/19 10:05", "25/6/19 16:40", "25/6/19 17:10", "25/6/19 17:40", 
"25/6/19 18:10", "25/6/19 18:40", "25/6/19 19:10", "25/6/19 7:05", 
"25/6/19 7:35", "25/6/19 8:05", "25/6/19 8:20", "25/6/19 8:35", 
"25/6/19 9:05", "25/6/19 9:35", "27/5/19 16:30", "27/5/19 17:00", 
"27/5/19 17:03", "27/5/19 17:30", "27/5/19 18:00", "27/5/19 18:30", 
"27/5/19 19:00", "27/5/19 19:20", "28/5/19 10:00", "28/5/19 10:30", 
"28/5/19 10:45", "28/5/19 11:00", "28/5/19 11:30", "28/5/19 12:00", 
"28/5/19 12:13", "28/5/19 12:30", "28/5/19 13:00", "28/5/19 13:30", 
"28/5/19 14:00", "28/5/19 14:30", "28/5/19 14:50", "28/5/19 16:15", 
"28/5/19 16:45", "28/5/19 17:15", "28/5/19 17:49", "28/5/19 18:15", 
"28/5/19 18:33", "28/5/19 18:45", "28/5/19 19:10", "28/5/19 7:00", 
"28/5/19 7:15", "28/5/19 7:30", "28/5/19 8:00", "28/5/19 8:30", 
"28/5/19 9:00", "28/5/19 9:12", "28/5/19 9:30", "28/8/19 16:45", 
"28/8/19 17:15", "28/8/19 17:45", "28/8/19 18:15", "28/8/19 18:45", 
"28/8/19 6:55", "28/8/19 7:25", "28/8/19 7:55", "28/8/19 8:25", 
"28/8/19 8:55", "28/8/19 9:25", "28/8/19 9:55", "29/11/19 10:05", 
"29/11/19 7:05", "29/11/19 7:35", "29/11/19 7:50", "29/11/19 8:05", 
"29/11/19 8:35", "29/11/19 9:05", "29/11/19 9:35", "29/5/19 10:20", 
"29/5/19 10:50", "29/5/19 11:20", "29/5/19 11:37", "29/5/19 11:50", 
"29/5/19 12:07", "29/5/19 12:20", "29/5/19 12:50", "29/5/19 13:20", 
"29/5/19 13:50", "29/5/19 14:20", "29/5/19 14:50", "29/5/19 15:20", 
"29/5/19 15:50", "29/5/19 16:20", "29/5/19 16:50", "29/5/19 17:20", 
"29/5/19 17:29", "29/5/19 17:39", "29/5/19 17:50", "29/5/19 18:20", 
"29/5/19 18:50", "29/5/19 19:20", "29/5/19 7:20", "29/5/19 7:47", 
"29/5/19 7:50", "29/5/19 8:20", "29/5/19 8:43", "29/5/19 8:50", 
"29/5/19 9:20", "29/5/19 9:50", "3/10/19 10:10", "3/10/19 15:55", 
"3/10/19 16:25", "3/10/19 16:55", "3/10/19 17:25", "3/10/19 17:42", 
"3/10/19 17:55", "3/10/19 18:25", "3/10/19 18:50", "3/10/19 7:00", 
"3/10/19 7:11", "3/10/19 7:28", "3/10/19 7:40", "3/10/19 8:05", 
"3/10/19 8:10", "3/10/19 8:40", "3/10/19 9:10", "3/10/19 9:40", 
"31/1/20 16:20", "31/1/20 16:50", "31/1/20 17:20", "31/1/20 17:40", 
"31/1/20 17:50", "31/1/20 18:20", "31/1/20 7:10", "31/1/20 7:40", 
"31/1/20 8:10", "31/1/20 8:40", "6/12/19 17:07", "6/12/19 17:35", 
"6/12/19 18:15", "6/12/19 18:47", "7/1/20 10:00", "7/1/20 16:15", 
"7/1/20 16:45", "7/1/20 17:15", "7/1/20 17:45", "7/1/20 18:15", 
"7/1/20 18:29", "7/1/20 18:45", "7/1/20 7:30", "7/1/20 8:00", 
"7/1/20 8:30", "7/1/20 9:00", "7/1/20 9:30", "7/6/19 10:10", 
"7/6/19 16:10", "7/6/19 16:40", "7/6/19 17:10", "7/6/19 17:40", 
"7/6/19 18:10", "7/6/19 18:40", "7/6/19 19:10", "7/6/19 7:50", 
"7/6/19 8:20", "7/6/19 8:42", "7/6/19 8:50", "7/6/19 9:20", "7/6/19 9:45", 
"8/7/19 16:05", "8/7/19 17:35", "8/7/19 18:05", "8/7/19 18:35", 
"8/7/19 19:05", "8/7/19 6:55", "8/7/19 7:25", "8/7/19 7:55", 
"8/7/19 8:10", "8/7/19 8:25", "8/7/19 8:55", "8/7/19 9:25", "8/7/19 9:30", 
"8/7/19 9:55", "8/8/19 10:10", "8/8/19 15:55", "8/8/19 16:25", 
"8/8/19 16:31", "8/8/19 16:55", "8/8/19 17:25", "8/8/19 17:32", 
"8/8/19 17:55", "8/8/19 18:25", "8/8/19 18:55", "8/8/19 19:20", 
"8/8/19 7:10", "8/8/19 7:40", "8/8/19 8:10", "8/8/19 8:40", "8/8/19 9:10", 
"8/8/19 9:40", "9/9/19 10:05", "9/9/19 10:20", "9/9/19 16:50", 
"9/9/19 17:20", "9/9/19 17:50", "9/9/19 18:05", "9/9/19 18:20", 
"9/9/19 18:35", "9/9/19 18:50", "9/9/19 19:15", "9/9/19 7:05", 
"9/9/19 7:35", "9/9/19 7:52", "9/9/19 7:55", "9/9/19 8:05", "9/9/19 8:20", 
"9/9/19 8:35", "9/9/19 9:05", "9/9/19 9:35", "9/9/19 9:55"), class = "factor"), 
    troop = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Main", 
    "Sub-Group"), class = "factor"), survey_method = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Ad_libitum", "Scan"), class = "factor"), 
    data_tag = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L), .Label = c("NSF-B1", 
    "NSF-B2", "NSF-F1", "NSF-F2", "NSF-F3", "NSF-M10a", "NSF-M10b", 
    "NSF-M1a", "NSF-M1a/R1", "NSF-M1b", "NSF-M1b/R4", "NSF-M2a", 
    "NSF-M2b", "NSF-M3a", "NSF-M3b", "NSF-M4a", "NSF-M4b", "NSF-M5a", 
    "NSF-M5b", "NSF-M6a", "NSF-M6b", "NSF-M7a", "NSF-M7b", "NSF-M8a", 
    "NSF-M8b", "NSF-M9a", "NSF-M9b", "NSF-P1", "NSF-P2", "NSF-P3", 
    "NSF-R2", "NSF-R3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(581L, 
582L, 583L, 584L, 585L, 586L, 587L, 588L, 575L, 576L, 577L, 578L, 
579L, 580L, 377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L), class = "data.frame")

#reorder timestamps in ascending order
df<-df[order(df$timestamp),]

#remove duplicates
df <- df[!duplicated(df$timestamp),]

m <- df2move(df, x = df$"location.long", y=df$"location.lat",
            time=as.POSIXct(df$"timestamp",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="Singapore"),
            proj ="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs", 
            removeDuplicatedTimestamps=T)

#>Error: Column named '103.78751' cannot be found in 'df'.
```

I have no idea why df's being mentioned in this error code and 103.78751 is a row and not column. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read `?df2move` it expects `x`, `y`, and `time` column to be the name of the column and not the values. Also, `time` column needs to be of class `POSIXct`. So try :

```
df$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df$timestamp, format = '%d/%m/%y %H:%M', tz='Singapore')

m <- moveVis::df2move(df, x = 'location.long', y= 'location.lat',
                         time= 'timestamp',
                         proj ="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs", 
                         removeDuplicatedTimestamps=T)

m
#class       : Move 
#features    : 20 
#extent      : 103.7841, 103.7895, 1.399946, 1.40375  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#variables   : 3
#names       :         x,           y,       time 
#min values  :  103.78411, 1.399945971, 1560328800 
#max values  : 103.789537, 1.403750014, 1584011100 
#timestamps  : 2019-06-12 16:40:00 ... 2020-03-12 19:05:00 Time difference #of 274 days  (start ... end, duration) 
#sensors     : unknown 
#indiv. data :  
#indiv. value:  
#date created: 2020-04-26 15:27:31
```

Comment: ah I didn't realise that using $ gives the values and not the col name.  thank you for clarifying!

Comment: Is it possible instead to change the class of timestamp in df2move? I tried to do that using the same code and it gives me NA, which is weird!

Comment: As far as I read `?df2move` I don't think you can do any data manipulation in `df2move`. Whatever changes you have to make in data do it before calling `df2move`.